# why $items is Null

Tags: php, null

I have this line in my code:

```
$item=$page->items;
```

`$page` is an array, and its content is as it should be but `$item` is Null. do you have any idea what could be the reason?

UPDATE:

```
<?php

search( "Steve Jobs" );

// Submit query to Google Web Search
function search( $query )
{
  $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=YOUR_KEY&cx=YOUR_SEARCHE_NGINE_ID&q=" . urlencode( $query ) .  "&callback=handleResponse&prettyprint=true&num=10";

  $result = get_web_page( $url );

  // Exception handling
  if ( $result['http_code'] == 403 )
      echo "... error: daily limit exceeded ...";
  if ( $result['errno'] != 0 )
      echo "... error: bad url, timeout, redirect loop ...";
  if ( $result['http_code'] != 200 )
      echo "... error: no page, no permissions, no service ...";
  // Get and parse JSON output
  $page = $result['content']; 

  $page = str_replace("// API callback\nhandleResponse(", "", $page);
  $page = str_replace(");", "", $page);    
  $page=json_decode($page, true);

  // Print results

$items=$page->items;
     var_dump($items);

  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($items); $i++)
  {
      $item = $items[$i];
      print("<font size=\"3\">" . "<a href=\"" . $item->link . "\" target=\"_blank\">" . $item->htmlTitle . "</a></font><br>");
      print("<font size=\"2\" color=\"black\">" . $item->htmlSnippet . "</font><br>");
      print("<font size=\"2\" color=\"green\">" . $item->displayLink . "</font><br>");      print("<br>");
  }

}


function get_web_page( $url )
{
  $options = array(
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
      CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
      CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
      CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
  );

  $ch = curl_init( $url );
  curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
 // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  $content = curl_exec( $ch );
  $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
  $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
  $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );

  $header['errno']   = $err;
  $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
  $header['content'] = $content;
  return $header;
}

?>
```

ANSWER:

this part should be changed since $page is an array.

```
$items = $page['items'];
    foreach ($items as $item)
  {
      $item = (object) $item;
      print("<font size=\"3\">" . "<a href=\"" . $item->link . "\" target=\"_blank\">" . $item->htmlTitle . "</a></font><br>");
      print("<font size=\"2\" color=\"black\">" . $item->htmlSnippet . "</font><br>");
      print("<font size=\"2\" color=\"green\">" . $item->displayLink . "</font><br>");      print("<br>");
  }
```

Comment: Specifying what language you are using would help a lot. It looks like c++ but is impossible to tell with so little code.

Comment: If this is PHP code then this isn't how you access the items inside the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple question, simple answer:

`$item` is `NULL` because `$page->items` is `NULL`.

More details:

You're treating `$page` as an object, but you write it's an array.

Suggestion:

Treat `$page` as an array instead.

Further information:

The [PHP manual](http://php.net/docs) has information how to treat a value [like an array](http://php.net/array) or [like an object](http://php.net/object). Additionally if you enable warnings on your development box, you will be notified about undefined properties which are always `NULL`.

**Update:**

For your concrete code, with a slight modification this should work, just change your for loop a bit:

```
  foreach ($items as $item)
  {
      $item = (object) $item;
      print("<font size=\"3\">" . "<a href=\"" . $item->link . "\" target=\"_blank\">" . $item->htmlTitle . "</a></font><br>");
      print("<font size=\"2\" color=\"black\">" . $item->htmlSnippet . "</font><br>");
      print("<font size=\"2\" color=\"green\">" . $item->displayLink . "</font><br>");      print("<br>");
  }
```

Comment: have a look to an UPDATE pls.

Comment: Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php - You get json objects as associative arrays, so use the return value as array (not object), see [Shakti's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193193/why-items-is-null/8193208#8193208) for a more concrete example. My answer focusses on the explanation and the basic knowledge, which you should learn to understand the issue.

Comment: Updated the answer as well, because you just have blindly applied what Shakti suggested, but you have the same sort of problem as well inside the loop. You should really start to understand why it happens to you so you can deal with these type of errors on your own.

Comment: but what you have suggested doesn't work either. before the loop starts, $item is NULL.

Comment: Don't use `$item=$page->items;`, use `$items = $page['items'];`. Understand what you access and how for what. Understand what an array is and what an object is and what `json_decode` returns. `var_dump` is your friend, really. It's hard at the beginning but once you figured it out and played around a bit, this becomes very easy.

Comment: dear harke, I checked both. in both case var_dump($item) returns NULL

Comment: Try `var_dump($page)` as well, so you *know* what you try to access. That's more important.

Comment: Also enable error reporting / display. You will be notified about places where you made some errors, so you don't look at the wrong place. Fix all warnings then it's easier to deal with problems. That's really helpful for developing.

Comment: I am working with IE. I have disabled "disable script debugging". should I do something else?

Comment: That's not inside your browser but in the PHP configuration, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.errorfunc.php

Answer (score 1):

*$page is an array, and its content is as it should be*

If `$page` is an array, you should access it like

```
$item=$page['items'];
```

If you provide more info you would get more helpful answer.

**EDIT**

First, Please make sure you have `$page` not empty at all.

What you have is `$page=json_decode($page, true);` that return an associative array and you should use the way I posted above.

If you don't want the array to be returned you should change your `json_decode` to return object by not passing second argument as `true`.
`$page=json_decode($page);` then you are okay with the code you have right now.

Comment: more info is provides as an UPDATE!

Answer (score 0):

If `$page` is array you do this `$page['items']`. If it is **JSON or XML** you can also access ait the way you are doing. like $page->items;

Comment: actually I am working on json/Atom custom search API of google, I have found an example and trying to work with it. I will add the whole code as an update

Comment: @nasi Ok. Post it and I would assist